# How to invert the y-axis in ngx-chart line chart

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

If we look at the [ngx-charts line chart demo](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/line-chart), we can see the y-axis displayed by default as:

[image]

Is there a way to invert the y-axis, so that it looks like this instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a workaround for this:

If you multiplied all your values by -1 when setting the data, then in the label formatting multiplied them all by -1 again, the order would be reversed but the label would be unchanged.

So your data would be [-3000,-4000,-5000,-6000], putting them in the 'correct' order, then your formatting would be

```
  yAxisTickFormatting = (value) => {

return value * -1;
```

};

giving you the desired effect.

stackBlitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-ngx-charts-emac6m?file=src/app/app.component.ts